# How to check if a file exists on a remote server

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to test if a file exists somewhere on a remote Linux server (e.g., /var/run/test_daemon.pid), without logging in to the server interactively. For example, you may want your script to behave differently depending on whether or not a specific file exists on a remote server.

Comment: Uhm... `ssh user@host test -f filename` ?

Answer (score 1):

The following command will do, if you know exactly where the file is located

```
  ssh user@remote_server  test -f  /path/to/file/filename && echo "YES" || echo "no"
```

You need the piece beginning with `&&` because test will not produce any output, and you won't be able to tell whether the file has been found or not.

Otherwise, if you only know the name of the file but are unsure as to its whereabouts,

```
 ssh user@remote_server find / -type f -name 'name_of_file*' -print
```

will search through the whole file system for your file.

Notice the use of ssh: it connects to the remote server, executes the command following the expression `user@remote_server`, but will not open an interactive session: control will be returned to the shell on your local pc.

Comment: If you are scripting, echoing is pointless - `ssh` will set the correct return code, which you can then check with `$?`. Having it print a string to standard out is clunky. If you are not scripting, why the heck would you need a non-interactive method?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, you are right, I forgot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ "`ssh -q user@hostname ls /dir/filename.abc 2>dev/null`" == "/dir/filename.abc" ]] 
then 
echo "file exists"
else
echo "file does not exist"
fi
```